# User to User Model: One to Many Relationship on Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm doing a project for one of my University courses. But I'm finding it difficult to make relationship between `User` to `User` model.

Table: `users`

- id
- name
- email
- type
- password

On this table the column `type` is used for classifying user types.
For example: User can be either `distributor` or `dealer` type.

And a `distributor` may have many `dealer`
But a `dealer` may have only one `distributor`.

To implement this I've created another table and named as `dealers_of_distributor`.

Table: `dealers_of_distributor`

- id
- distributor_id  (id of users table)
- dealer_id  (id of users table)

Although I've used an additional model `DelaersOfDistributor`, the exact relationship should be between `user` to `user`.

How can I make this relationship. I'm confused!

I've tried so far:
Model: `User`

```
public function dealersOfDistributor(){
    $this->hasMany('App\DealersOfDistributor');
}
```

Model: `DealersOfDistributor`

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

The `DistributorsController`

```
public function index()
{
    $distributors=User::where('type', 'distributor')->get();
    $dealers=User::where('type', 'dealer')->get();
    $assignedDealers=DealersOfDistributor::all();

    return view('distributors.index')->withDistributors($distributors)->withDealers($dealers)->with('assignedDealers', $assignedDealers);
}
```

In `blade` file: I've tried `$assignedDealer->dealer_id->user->name`. But It's showing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model DealersOfDistributor:

```
public function distributorUser()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'distributor_id', 'id');
}

public function dealerUser()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'dealer_id', 'id');

}
```

than you just get the user's data from DealersOfDistributor model, call function dealerUser if you want get user's data from dealer_id, and call function distributionUser if you want get user's data from distribution_id

Controller:

```
    public function index()
{
    $assignedDealers=DealersOfDistributor::all();

    return view('distributors.index',compact('assignedDealers'));
}
```

Blade get username:

```
 @foreach($assignedDealers as $assign)


    {{$assign->distributorUser->name}}
{{$assign->dealerUser->name}}

     @endforeach
```

Comment: But how can I get user name in `Blade` file ?

Comment: Thanks, you're my lifesaver.

Comment: One more thing, how can I `sync` data in `dealers_of_distributor` table by controller @Vynart

Comment: @SMIftakhairul i have edited my answer, how to get the username from dealers_of_distributor table